# LWC/ How would I get the record ID after createRecord api?

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components

```
const fields = {};
        fields[NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.name;
        const recordInput = { apiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields };
        createRecord(recordInput)
            .then(beep => {
                this.accountId = beep.id;

            });
            console.log(this.accountId);
```

The console returns 'undefined'. How would I be able to get the Id? (@track accountId defined)

Comment: It returns an ID, can you add catch block as mentioned here to see ifthere are any errors?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/data_salesforce_write

Comment: There are no errors, but this.accountId still  remains undefined in the function. For  Clarification: I am calling this function  through a lightning-button.

Comment: Shoudn't `console.log(this.accountId);` be inside the then block?

Comment: Yeah you are right. But why is it necessary for it to be inside the block?

Comment: Is there a way to get the Id of the record created immediately so it can be used elsewhere?

Comment: like @PranayJaiswal said, you need that log inside the block, i think that your problem is with the "this" context, try to define a variable before the code and assign the value inside the .then block.

Comment: hmm that doesn't seem to change the outcome(undefined). Based on what @PranayJaiswal said would it even be possible, for example to create a record and then update another field  with the created record's Id?

Comment: figured it out, you can use triggers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createRecord` is serverside call, and hence it's asynchronous in nature.

Now the thing about the async process is the returned value will only be present in the then block.

Let's look at the below piece of code.

```
createMyAccount(event){
            const fields = {};
            fields[NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.name;
            const recordInput = { apiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields };
            createRecord(recordInput)
                .then(beep => {
                    this.accountId = beep.id;

                });
            console.log(this.accountId);
        }
```

`createMyAccount` is an syncronous method, it sets the fields and triggeres the async process `create record`. The `console.log(this.accountId);` is part of sync process, and thus it returns undefined.

When you move it to `then` block, it will run when server finishes creating record, and as record creation was successful you will get Id.

```
createMyAccount(event){
            const fields = {};
            fields[NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.name;
            const recordInput = { apiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields };
            createRecord(recordInput)
                .then(beep => {
                    this.accountId = beep.id;
                    console.log(this.accountId);

                });

        }
```

So whatever operation you have to do with that Id, you have to do it in then block/

Src: https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for clarifying